# Add Another Column Info to Results of groupby r

Tags: r, dplyr

Can someone help me please?

I Have Column A, Column B and Column C, I want to get the top value of column C, grouped by A, but also have the information of B for those top values

```
Max <-X  %>% select(A,B,C) %>%  group_by(A) %>% summarise(top = max(C))
```

But this code only show me the top values of each unique A data, so I dont know whats the B value assigned to that.  (Important, making `group_by(A,B)` doesnt work, because it doesnt give the top values for each unique A value, it returns the same as the data base X)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be achieved via `dplyr::top_n` or `? dplyr::slice_max` like so:

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars  %>% select(cyl, mpg, hp) %>% group_by(cyl) %>% top_n(1, hp)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl   mpg    hp
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4  30.4   113
#> 2     6  19.7   175
#> 3     8  15     335

mtcars  %>% select(cyl, mpg, hp) %>% group_by(cyl) %>% slice_max(hp)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 3
#> # Groups:   cyl [3]
#>     cyl   mpg    hp
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1     4  30.4   113
#> 2     6  19.7   175
#> 3     8  15     335
```

So, in your case it should be:

```r
Max <-X  %>% select(A,B,C) %>%  group_by(A) %>% slice_max(C)
```